# Creating pill buttons using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, button, tailwind-css

I have this button:

```html
<button onClick={() => removeTask(task)} class="text-xs text-red rounded-full">Delete</button>
```

I was hoping to see something like:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-radius#pill-buttons

However, I'm not getting pill-shaped buttons:

[image]

**index.css**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```

Comment: Are you able to apply any tailwind classes at all?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the "pill" shape, your button needs a border or background color. You could try something like:

```html
<button class="rounded-full text-xs font-bold text-white bg-red-500 py-1 px-2">Delete</button>
```

Sandbox example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/j6K2e6ZL0J